# how do i create a group and sort list compatible with angularjs and bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint

Hi i have data like this. (basic example)

- fruit, apple, $1
- fruit, orange, $1
- fruit, banana, $1
- vegetable, sprouts, $2
- vegetable, carrots, $1
- Drink, water, $1
- Drink, milk, $2

I would like to have a list that will group by fruit/vegetables/drinks (maybe with an accordion)
Then can be sorted by the sub category (apple for example) (the group sorting order stays as is, the sub items can be sorted a>z  z>a).

the price needs to be click-able so the user can change the values, so the container needs to be rich html elements. (dropdowns etc)

Filtering is also a bonus.

i will be using angularJS for the databinding. and bootstrap is also used.

*for your reference the data is coming from a SharePoint list, and i'm trying to mimic the grouping sorting of list behaviour, but using angular for single page app.

here is an example

[image]
Can anyone recommend something that fits this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. I used AngularUI accordion, then Lodash to group and sort.